# How to get information from object in C# Visual Studio that used JSON string to object method?

Tags: c#, json

How to get information from object in C# Visual Studio that used JSON string to object method?

```
string jsonStr = "[{'Name':'John Simith','Age':35},{'Name':'Pablo Perez','Age':'34'}]";

JavaScriptSerializer jsss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
objectstrPDItem = jsss.Deserialize(jsonStr, typeof(object));
```

How to get information from `objectstrPDItem`?

Comment: What kind of information are you looking for?

Comment: Personally, I'd go with @Serge's answer. But. If you are married to something like `object`, go with `dynamic` instead (just swap your `object` with `dynamic` (or, `dynamic[]`))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works great for me:
https://forums.asp.net/t/2099529.aspx?Decoding+of+json+data+failing+using+json+net

```
JArray jsonVal = JArray.Parse(jsonStr) as JArray;
dynamic albumsjsonVal = jsonValDenis;
foreach (dynamic album in albumsjsonVal)
{
    var test = album.id;
    var testname = album.name; 
    //Response.Write(album.id + "  --  " + album.paymentDue + "  <br />");
```

}

Comment: I don't understand the logic in this answer. You make and assign a variable `jsonVal`, but don't do anything with it, then magically `jsonValDenis` comes into being.

Comment: This doesn't deserialize the JSON in the question.

Answer (score 3):

try this using Newtonsoft.Json

```
List<Person> persons = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(jsonStr);
```

class

```
 public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

test

```
foreach (var person in persons) Console.WriteLine($"({person.Name},{person.Age})");
```

output

```
(John Simith,35)
(Pablo Perez,34)
```